GooglePlayPlatform plugin for Unity, doesn't work
I checked the apk on honor 10i and everything works fine, the pop-up window appears, but as soon as I check on newer phone models like redmi 9, Xiaomi redmi note 12 pro 5g and other newer phone models GooglePlayGamesPlatform does not work, there is no pop-up window  , I've been trying to solve this problem for several days now and can't figure out what the problem is(https://i.sstatic.net/LfySt.jpg)(https://i.sstatic.net/ChbYN.jpg)
I tried changing the project configuration, rechecked SHA-1, but nothing helps, I think the problem is that the plugin works on older phone models, but does not work on new phone models, minimum api level 5.1, target api lvl highest.

Are you using the latest version of SDK distributed on the Firebase site? Older versions of SDK found on the internet may not support newer phones.
If a crash occurred when downloading the SDK from the Firebase site, please let us know which SDK module you used.
Please note that if you do not absolutely need the Analytics module, only download the "Auth" module and the "Database" module.
